# Is Surtur under Loki's mind control?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, we saw that an army of dead was resurrected with the help of eternal flame. And the people who came back were under the control of Hela, person who used eternal flame to wake them.

So Loki used eternal flame to wake Surtur.

Then does that mean Surtur is under Loki's control? Is that a clue to the plot of an upcoming movie?

Comment: Hela used the Eternal Flame to resurrect people who had previously been loyal to her. I don't recall any indication that they were actually bound to her will in any way.

Comment: Isn't Surtur dead?

Answer (score 14):

Surtur will not be under Loki's mind control.

The army of the dead whom Hela resurrected were her loyal allies from her past and were under her control before their death. Fenris wolf, the loyal pet of Hela was also brought to life along with them.

It is clear from her dialogues and the pictures on the ceilings before she resurrects them. We can see the pictures of the army who were under the control of Hela and supported her.

[image: Hela along with Odin supported by her army forces]

> Hela: Before that, Asgard's warriors were on it. Their bodies buried as heroes beneath this very pass.
>
> Hela: My God! what they have done to you?....
>
> With the eternal flame, you are reborn.
>
> (After resurrection..)
>
> Hela: I missed you. I missed you all.

Surtur is neither a loyal person to Loki in anyway nor a friend to him. So, he would not be under the control of Loki.

Comment: "Her dog" is some hollywood version of Fenris. All dead and unchained (i.e. not considered dangerous by the Asir).

Answer (score 2):

No

We see Hela take some of the eternal flame, manipulate it, and harness it's powers to return her former comrades. The flame even turns green to represent that the bit she's using is under her influence.

That is not how Surtur's Resurrection worked. He stated at the start of the movie his goal was to place his crown inside the eternal flame, harness it's power and be reborn the size of a mountain. Loki simply did the placing. (Why they brought the item that would bring Ragnarok to the same place as the power it needed to do so is another question...)

So by my interpretation, Hela took the flame and used it. Loki did not. Instead *Surtur himself* used it once his crown was placed inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Surtur is under Loki's control. If he had control over Surtur he could have stayed back in Asgard, but instead he travels along with Thor and the people of Asgard.

Surtur destroys Asgard entirely so is obviously not under the control of Loki.

Comment: Surtur completely destroying Asgard was the entire plan, since that's where Hela drew all of her power from. The fact that Loki didn't stop him from doing so isn't proof that he couldn't have done so.

Comment: @iandotkelly I agree with you on that